# Multimedia keys (XF86Audio*) not shown by xev, even though still working

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, multimedia, xubuntu

I'm using a Lenovo SL400 laptop, and even though the audio multimedia keys (*XF86AudioPlay*, *XF86AudioStop*, *XF86AudioPrev* and *XF86AudioNext*) are not shown with `xev`, they work anyway with `Gmusicbrowser`, `Exaile` and `Rhythmbox`.

I'm not using `xbindkeys` nor `xmodmaprc`.

Is this something normal? If `xev` doesn't *see* these keys, why those multimedia apps respond to them?

**Edit:**

I'm using Xubuntu 11.04, and with version 10.10 these keys were recognized by `xev`.

And with Xfce running on 11.04, through *Settings manager*, section *Keyboard*, these keys can be mapped to whaterever the user wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is twofold:

These music players don't react to the keystrokes themselves, but to some D-Bus events from the `gnome-settings-daemon`.

The `gnome-settings-daemon` might have grabbed them in a way that `xev` no longer sees them.

Other players, their plugins or other software might however try to access these keys directly and fail (since `g-s-d` already owns them).